# SSL_read() does not return after successful handshake

Tags: c++, c, sockets, select, openssl

I made a server and a client, and they communicate in a secure TLSv1.3, OpenSSL 3.0.0 channel. They have to be able to send and receive, but in this test the server only receives, and the client only sends application data periodically.

After the successful handshake, the clients `select()` signals that there is data available to read. When I try to, `SSL_read()` does not return. I checked the network traffic in wireshark, and debugged the OpenSSL library to find out, that 2 *SESSION_TICKET* are sent after the handshake by the server to the client, and that is the message `SSL_read()` fails to process. Just for curiosity, I sent a message with the server right after the handshake to see how the client reacts to it. Surprisingly the client left its blocked state and the communication worked fine after that.

Due to the observed behavior, my only guess is that I try to read data meant for OpenSSL which is probably processed by its state machine when I call `SSL_read()`. When the library calls `read()` there is actually no application data available, so it blocks the thread.

The member function which I use to read "count" bytes can be seen below.

```
int EventHandler::readByte(CommBuffer &buffer, ssize_t count, struct timeval &tmout){
  fd_set rfds;
  int retSelect, retRead;
  int readByte=0;
  int endRead=0;
  int readSize=count;

  buffer.setBufferSize(count+1);
  do{
    FD_ZERO(&rfds);
    FD_SET(fd,&rfds);
    retSelect=select(fd+1,&rfds,NULL,NULL,&tmout);
    if(retSelect>0){
      if (encryptionOn) {
        retRead = SSL_read(ssl, (const_cast<char*>(&buffer.get()[readByte])), readSize); // Thread blocks here.
      } else {
        retRead = read(fd, (const_cast<char*>(&buffer.get()[readByte])), readSize);
      }
      if( retRead > 0 ){
        readByte+=retRead;
        allReadBytes+=retRead;
        buffer.setDataSize(readByte);
        if(readByte>=count) endRead=1;
        readSize=count-readByte;
      }
      else{
        if( retRead == -1 && errno == EINTR  ){
          continue;
        }
        if(fd>=0){
          close(fd);
        }
        fd=CLOSED_FD;
        return (CLOSED_FD);
      }
    }
    else if(retSelect==0){
      // handle timeout error
      return(TIMEOUT_FD);
    }
    else{
      return(retSelect);
    }
  }while(endRead!=1);
  return(readByte);
}
```

Note that this function works just fine without encryption. (`read()` instead of `SSL_read()`)

- What am I doing wrong?
- How should I read data?
- How would you modify this function?

Comment: If your client iis only sending why are to reacting to read events at all?

Comment: Both the client and a server is capable of reading and writing, but during this test, the server only reads and the client only writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` works at the TCP level while `SSL_read` works at the TLS level. `SSL_read` on a blocking socket will (usually) only return when application data are available while `select` will signal when any kind of data are available on the socket, i.e. also for non-application records or incomplete SSL frames.

In your specific case these data are the session tickets which with TLS 1.3 are no longer send as part of the TLS handshake but after the handshake. But, with lower TLS versions it could also happen that `SSL_read` blocked even if `select` returned that data are available: application data in TLS are send within SSL frames and it could happen that `select` signaled available data even though only part of the SSL frame is available. In this case `SSL_read` would block until the full SSL frame could be read. Also, `SSL_read` would block on  SSL renegotiations even if `select` would signal available data.

Moreover, it could happen that `select` would not signal available data but `SSL_read` would return some. This is the case when the previous `SSL_read` did not consume all data which were included in the last SSL frames already read from the TCP socket.

In other words: `select` should not be used with blocking sockets in SSL. Instead the sockets should be made non-blocking so that `SSL_read` (and other functions) can fail with `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` or `SSL_ERROR_WANT_WRITE` which one should handle as documented. Additionally `SSL_pending` should be called to check for data which were were already read from the TCP socket but which were not yet consumed by `SSL_read`.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to modify the socket to be non-blocking, and try to use ```SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ```. I will notify you about my experiences when I am done.

Comment: Bad info. Don't just change the socket to nbio just to make it work. That's a hack. You're hacking your way to a solution. You use nbio if you can get some other work done in the event loop. If not then leave the socket as blocking. So you need to know (and can know) how much data to expect before calling SSL_read(). The amount of data on the socket will not be the same amount as the amount of data at the SSL layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a blocking socket, it may be possible that mode `SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY` is enabled. this may cause a hang on the `SSL_read` in case there's no application data to be read.
In this case, you can either disable this mode (but you will need to handle an `SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ` error), or use non-blocking sockets.
I suggest you You can read about [SSL_MODE_AUTO_RETRY](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/man3/SSL_CTX_set_mode.html).